# iframe layout in Html5

Tags: css, html, iframe

I want to use iframes for html5 layout for some reason.  Want the panelframe and bodyframe to occupy the full height of the browser leaving 56px at top for header and 54px at bottom for footer.  But the following code is not working.

```
<iframe name="headerframe" width="100%" height="56" frameborder="0" src="header.html"></iframe>

<iframe name="panelframe" width="300" height="95%" frameborder="0" src="panel.html"></iframe>

<iframe name="bodyframe" width="auto" height="95%" frameborder="0" src="body.html" ></iframe>

<iframe name="footerframe" width="100%" height="54" frameborder="0" src="footer.html" ></iframe>
```

Any help?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? This smells like an unecessary frame abomination. You know that you can style and position elements on a page without those iframes, do you?

Comment: Could you post the code on jsfiddle?

Comment: are you building a phishing website? this code makes no sense, please post jfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L3tJR/

Comment: This has voip phone application, so the page should not reload at any time by clicking the menus or any links.

Comment: @Paramasivan [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) to the rescue!

Comment: It will be difficult to maintain the site with Ajax or jQuery

Answer (score 2):

check this out, styling wbsites is very easy

```
<div style="padding-top:54px;padding-bottom:54px" > 
    <iframe name="headerframe" width="100%" height="100" frameborder="0" src="header.html"></iframe>

    <iframe name="panelframe" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="panel.html"></iframe>

    <iframe name="bodyframe" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="body.html" ></iframe>

    <iframe name="footerframe" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="footer.html" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: this works, but I HIGHLY Recommend using AJAX instead of iFrames

Comment: Still footer is in middle of the screen.

Comment: I HIGHLY Recommend using AJAX instead of iFrames